# Tic Tac Toe in C++ with classes

Tags: c++, performance, tic-tac-toe, classes

My first language is Python and I learned considerably a good amount of it. So now I started learning C++. I know the basics of C++ and about classes and inheritance.

This is my first serious project with classes. (I am thinking of adding an ai)

I wanted to know where I could -

- Optimize the performance.
- Improve my class.
- Improve my win and draw detection functions. (Sadly, I cant use `... == ... ==... ==` in C++)

Here is my code -

```
#include <iostream>

class TicTacToe
{
private:
    char board[9] = {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '};
    char current_turn = 'X';
    bool playing = true;
    int state = 0;
    int input;

public:
    void print_board();
    int play_move(int index, char move);
    int check_win(char move);
    void start();
};

int main()
{
    TicTacToe game;
    game.start();
    return 0;
}

void TicTacToe :: start()
{
    while (playing == true)
    {
        print_board();
        std::cout << "Play your move " << current_turn << std::endl;
        std::cin >> input;
        if (play_move(input, current_turn) == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Box already occupied" << std::endl;
            continue;
        };
        state = check_win(current_turn);
        if (state == 1)
        {
            print_board();
            std::cout << current_turn << " wins the game!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        else if (state == 2)
        {
            std::cout << "Draw!" << std::endl;
            break;
        };
        current_turn = (current_turn == 'X') ? 'O' : 'X';
    };
};

void TicTacToe :: print_board()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1 || i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 5 || i == 7 || i == 8)
        {
            std::cout << " | ";
        }
        std::cout << board[i];
        if (i == 2 || i == 5)
        {
            std::cout << std::endl;
            std::cout << "---------" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
};

int TicTacToe :: play_move(int index, char move)
{
    if (index >= 0 && index < 9)
    {
        if (board[index] == ' ')
        {
            board[index] = move;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
};

/*
   0 1 2
   3 4 5
   6 7 8
*/
int TicTacToe ::check_win(char move)
{
    if (
        // Horizontal checks
        (board[0] == move && board[1] == move && board[2] == move) ||
        (board[3] == move && board[4] == move && board[5] == move) ||
        (board[6] == move && board[7] == move && board[8] == move) ||
        // Vertical Checks
        (board[0] == move && board[3] == move && board[6] == move) ||
        (board[1] == move && board[4] == move && board[7] == move) ||
        (board[2] == move && board[5] == move && board[8] == move) ||
        // Diagonal Checks
        (board[0] == move && board[4] == move && board[8] == move) ||
        (board[2] == move && board[4] == move && board[6] == move))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        bool draw = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if (board[i] == ' ')
            {
                draw = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (draw == true)
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Since you mention knowing Python, would you use a class to implement this in Python? I'm asking because, just like in Python, you would usually *not* use a class here in C++, as it's completely unnecessary and only makes your code more complex. If this confuses you, go watch [*Stop writing classes* by Jack Diederich](https://youtu.be/o9pEzgHorH0).

Comment: what means std::something, i thought using namespace std its enough to not declare that part

Comment: Using `using namespace std;` is considered to be a bad practice. Refer this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1452738/16246688).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the class first:

> ```
> class TicTacToe
> {
> private:
>     char board[9] = {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '};
>     char current_turn = 'X';
>     bool playing = true;
>     int state = 0;
>     int input;
>
> public:
>     void print_board();
>     int play_move(int index, char move);
>     int check_win(char move);
>     void start();
> };
> ```

All the state is private and the functions are all public - that seems sensible.  We can omit the `private:` label since that's the default for `class`, but it does no harm to have it, and it is more explicit.

The print and check functions shouldn't need to modify the state of the object, so they probably ought to be declared `const`:

```
    void print_board() const;
    int check_win(char move) const;
```

The function we've called `print_board()` is usually spelt `<<`, with the signature

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const TicTacToe&)
```

We need it to be a non-member function (and probably `friend` so it can read the innards of `TicTacToe` objects).

`start()` isn't a great name - it seems it plays a whole game.  I'd call it `play()` or `play_game()`.

It's not clear that `input` needs to be a member - usually inputs are transient values that only later translate into state changes.  The integer `state` is a very vague name; when I went to see where it's used, it seems it doesn't need to be a member either.

I would consider changing `current_turn` into something like `bool player_is_x` - that's easier to toggle (`player_is_x = !player_is_x`) and still quite simple to convert to the appropriate letter (`player_is_x ? 'X' : 'O'` - or more obscurely, `player_is_x["OX"]`, but really don't do that).

You might want to consider having a class to represent a board, and one that knows how to play the game (managing whose turn it is, etc.).

---

In a couple of places, we have redundant comparisons:

> ```
>     while (playing == true)
>
>     if (draw == true)
> ```

`while` and `if` accept booleans, so they can be simply:

> ```
>     while (playing)
>
>     if (draw)
> ```

We never write `if ((x == y) == true)`, do we?

---

The structure of `check_win()` is

> ```
> if (⋯)
> {
>     return 1;
> }
> else
> {
>     bool draw = true;
>     for (⋯)
>     {
>         if (⋯)
>         {
>             draw = false;
>             break;
>         }
>     }
>     if (draw == true)
>     {
>         return 2;
>     }
> }
> return 0;
> ```

Whenever we have `if (⋯) { return; }` any following `else` can just go directly after without the `else` keyword:

```
if (⋯)
{
    return 1;
}
bool draw = true;
for (⋯)
{
    if (⋯)
    {
        draw = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (draw == true)
{
    return 2;
}
return 0;
```

Now, the `draw` variable is only ever set to determine what to return.  But we can simply return immediately instead of setting it:

```
if (⋯)
{
    return 1;
}
for (⋯)
{
    if (⋯)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
return 2;
```

That's much simpler.  Simpler still (for the caller, too) is to have separate member functions to check for a win and for a draw.

When we're checking for a win, do you see any pattern in the cell indexes here?

> ```
>     // Horizontal checks
>     (board[0] == move && board[1] == move && board[2] == move) ||
>     (board[3] == move && board[4] == move && board[5] == move) ||
>     (board[6] == move && board[7] == move && board[8] == move) ||
>     // Vertical Checks
>     (board[0] == move && board[3] == move && board[6] == move) ||
>     (board[1] == move && board[4] == move && board[7] == move) ||
>     (board[2] == move && board[5] == move && board[8] == move) ||
>     // Diagonal Checks
>     (board[0] == move && board[4] == move && board[8] == move) ||
>     (board[2] == move && board[4] == move && board[6] == move)
> ```

Each straight-line check is an arithmetic progression, with a step of 1 for horizontal, 3 for vertical, 4 for major diagonal and 2 for minor diagonal.  So we could write a small (private) helper rather than writing out all cases like that:

```
bool TicTacToe::check_line(int pos, int step) const
{
    char val = board[pos];
    pos += step;
    if (board[pos] != val) { return false; }
    pos += step;
    if (board[pos] != val) { return false; }
    return true;
}

bool TicTacToe::check_win() const
{
    for (int i = 0;  i < 3;  ++i) {
        // horizontal line?
        if (check_line(i*3, 1)) { return true; }
        // vertical line?
        if (check_line(i, 3)) { return true; }
    }
    // diagonals
    return check_line(0, 4) || check_line(2, 2);
}

bool TicTacToe::check_draw() const
{
    for (char c: board) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

(Note that I didn't need to pass the current player here - if there's any line, it can only have been made in the most recent turn, or there would have been a win earlier).

And the call is just:

```
    if (check_win()) {
        print_board();
        std::cout << current_turn << " wins the game!\n";
        break;
    }
    if (check_draw()) {
        std::cout << "Draw!\n";
        break;
    };
```

---

When reading input, always check the stream state afterwards.  If the user enters something unexpected, the variable won't have a useful value:

```
    int input;
    std::cin >> input;
    if (!std::cin) {
        std::cerr << "Input error\n";
        return;
    }
```

Comment: `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const TicTacToe&)` I am new to this syntax, could you explain a bit more?

Comment: If you have ever written `std::cout << "Hello World!"`, that's what you're using.  It's how you implement a _stream insertion operator_ in C++.  See this [reference guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Stream_extraction_and_insertion) and [a tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/overloading-stream-insertion-and-extraction-operators-in-cplusplus).

Answer (score 3):

in `print_board`:

- instead of checking against all `i`s I would try to find a formula (probably containing a modulo) to check against once
- if you want to `cout`, don't put an `endl` at every line (it flushes the buffer to screen), use a simple `'\n'` and an `endl` or `flush` at the end.

in `check_win`:
instead of again doing all these separate comparisons, I might add up the contents of the possible winning lines and compare each with `3*move`

The last one of course is only viable if you can ensure that
`3*token1` is neither once nor twice the value of `token2` (which I haven't checked for 'X' and 'O' ...)

Draw detection:

```
bool draw = std::find(board, board+9, ' ') == board+9;
```

Comment: `if (i % 3)` =)

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "it flushes the buffer to the screen"?

Comment: @Random_Pythoneer59 `cout` is a "stream" object (it lives in the `iostream` header). It collects everything you stream into it (with the `<<` operator) in a buffer and does not immediately print it to screen. You need to `flush` the buffer to do so. `endl` does this implicitly every time you use it. So for better performance, avoid `endl` as a simple line-break if you don't need to actually print every single line separately.

Comment: Considering your other answer was not well received and on the verge of getting deleted by the community, I've merged your answers. It's quite possible the quality of your answer can be further improved by polishing it up a bit based on the comments you received. The comments can be found [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129998/discussion-on-answer-by-tino-michael-tic-tac-toe-in-c-with-classes).

Answer (score 3):

- Only the `start()` member function needs to be `public`. The other member functions can be `private`.
- Member functions that don't change any member variables in the class should be marked `const`, e.g. `void print_board() const;`
- `play_move` returns success or failure, so it should return a `bool` and not an `int`.
- It would be better to use an `enum` for `state`, instead of an `int`. That way we can use meaningful names, e.g.: `enum class State { undecided, tie, winner };`
- `state` doesn't need to be a member variable. It can be a local variable in `start()`.
- `playing` could also be a local variable, but since it's never set to `false` we don't actually need it! The loop in `start()` could just be `while (true) { ... }`.
- Note that when testing a `bool`ean variable like `playing` in a `while` or `if` condition, we should do `if (playing)`, not `if (playing == true)`. (It's already a boolean so we don't need the equality comparison!)
- `input` can also be a local variable... in fact the `current_turn` can also be a local variable, since we pass it everywhere we need it.

---

Rather than checking lots of magic numbers in `print_board`, we could iterate over rows and columns and calculate the relevant board index, e.g.:

```
    const int board_size = 3; // could be a static constant member variable in the class

    for (int y = 0; y != board_size; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x != board_size; ++x)
        {
            if (x != 0)
            {
                std::cout << " | ";
            }

            std::cout << board[y * board_size + x];
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "---------" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Be smart!!

Imagine it's Friday afternoon. You are feeling impressed with yourself for completing the assignment right on time and just when you are about close your little MacBook, your boss walks in and asks if you can modify your program to work on a 5 x 5 grid?  Tears run down your face as you realize that your weekend is ruined.
You should always code for reusability.

```
enum Diagonal
{
    Principle,
    Secondary
};

template <class T> class TicTacTo
{
private:
    std::size_t _rows;
    std::size_t _cols;
    T _emptySpace;
    std::vector<T> _cells = {};

public:
    TicTacTo(std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols, T _emptySpace)
      : _rows{rows},
        _cols{cols},
        _emptySpace{_emptySpace}
    {
        _cells.resize(rows * cols, _emptySpace);
    }

public:
    T& cell(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) {
        return _cells[col + row * _cols];
    }

    const std::vector<T> getCol(std::size_t col) {
        std::vector<T> v(_rows);
        for (std::size_t row = 0; row < _rows; row++)
            v[row] = cell(row, col);
        return v;
    }

    const std::vector<T> getRow(std::size_t row) {
        std::vector<T> v(_cols);
        for (std::size_t col = 0; col < _cols; col++)
            v[col] = cell(row, col);
        return v;
    }

    const std::vector<T> getDiagonal(Diagonal d) {
        std::vector<T> v;
        for (std::size_t col = 0; col < _cols; col++) {
            if (col < _rows) {
                v.push_back(cell(col, d == Diagonal::Principle ? col : _rows - col - 1));
            }
        }
        return v;
    }

    bool check_done() {
        return std::count(_cells.begin(), _cells.end(), _emptySpace) == 0;
    }

    bool check_equal(std::vector<T> v, T move) {
        return v[0] == move && std::equal(v.begin() + 1, v.end(), v.begin());
    }

    bool check_win(T move) {
        // check rows
        for (std::size_t r = 0; r < _rows; r++) {
            if (check_equal(getRow(r), move))
                return true;
        }
        // check columns
        for (std::size_t c = 0; c < _cols; c++) {
            if (check_equal(getCol(c), move))
                return true;
        }
        // check diagonals
        for (int d = 0; d < 2; d++) {
            if (check_equal(getDiagonal(d == 0 ? Diagonal::Principle : Diagonal::Secondary), move))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    void print() {
        for (std::size_t row = 0; row < _rows; row++) {
            for (std::size_t col = 0; col < _cols; col++) {
                std::cout << " " << cell(row, col);
                if (col < _cols - 1)
                    std::cout << " |";
            }
            if (row < _rows - 1) {
                std::cout << std::endl;
                for (std::size_t col = 0; col < _cols; col++) {
                    std::cout << (col < _cols - 1 ? "----" : "---");
                }
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    };
};

int main() {
    TicTacTo<char> ttt(5, 5, ' ');
    ttt.cell(0, 4) = 'x';
    ttt.cell(1, 3) = 'x';
    ttt.cell(2, 2) = 'x';
    ttt.cell(3, 1) = 'x';
    ttt.cell(4, 0) = 'x';
    ttt.print();

    std::cout << "win = " << ttt.check_win('x') << std::endl;
}
```

The next edit will replace `vector` with `valarray` and use `stride` etc.